# What is a great web meeting software similar to Cisco's Meeting Place?

Tags: netmeeting, conferencing

I don't know if any free software or service is out there.

I need to conduct some web meeting with my clients to just show some of products and presentations.  I've used Cisco's Meeting Place before, but I would like to see if there is anything free out there that can replace this job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [DimDim](http://www.dimdim.com/)
2. [Yuuguu](http://www.yuuguu.com/home)
3. [Vyew](http://vyew.com/site/)

Comment: I didn't check out #2 and #3, but DimDim is awesome. It fulfills my needs!

Comment: I remember hearing DimDim somewhere...did some company just acquire DimDim?

Comment: I don't think so. At least, it's not mentioned here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimdim

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Pascal Thivent's [options](https://superuser.com/questions/44608/what-is-a-great-web-meeting-software-similar-to-ciscos-meeting-place/44621#44621), there's also [FuzeMeeting](https://www.fuzemeeting.com/get-started) which I've started using off late.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer, I'm on the Yuuguu Dev Team)

[Yuuguu](http://www.yuuguu.com) would be able to provide what you need.  It is free, cross platform and secure.

There is also a web browser viewer available so only the host of a session needs to install the client (although you are limited to 100 minutes per month on the free version when sharing your screen this way).

Answer (score -1):

[Webex](http://www.webex.com/) - Used this one before, worked decently. This is the tried and true non-Microsoft solution. These guys have been around since '95 and seem to know what they are doing.

Comment: Not free. And, it's by Cisco.

Comment: yup. I know Webex, and it's definitely not free.